# What exactly happens if I add two dates in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me what happend here- I know it is stupid but I want to know.

The output of the below code is April-18-2105. How did it pop up?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date

firstDate = DateValue("Jun 19, 2010")
secondDate = DateValue("oct 29,1994")

MsgBox (firstDate + secondDate)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates are actually stored as numbers, so if we look at the numeric value for these dates:

```
CLng(datevalue("Jun 19, 2010")) '// 40348
CLng(datevalue("oct 29, 1994")) '// 34636
```

and add them together:

```
40348 + 34636 = 74984
```

and convert *that* number back to a date:

```
CDate(74984) '// 18/04/2105
```

Because it's 74,984 days after 00/01/1900

Answer (score 0):

dates are numbers, formatted as dd/mm/yyyy, I think its the days from 31/12/1899, so that's what's happening.  The result is 40348+34636=74984, which is 18/04/2105.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores the date as the number days after a specified date.  As such the integer representing the date of 2010/06/19 is 40348 and the integer representing 1994/10/29 is 34636.  When you add those integers together you get 74984 which is the integer that represents 2105/04/18.

The reference date does vary from [mac to windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-date-system-format-or-two-digit-year-interpretation-aaa2159b-4ae8-4651-8bce-d4707bc9fb9f).  I am running on windows and I did not change my reference date settings, That is where those integers came from.  Mac uses January 2nd 1904 as day 1 and Windows uses January 1 1900 as day 1.